# Can I remove double evaluation whilst keeping lambda expression

Tags: python, lambda, ternary-operator

```
def bar(x):
    # some expensive calculation
    <snip>

foo = lambda(x): bar(x) if bar(x) > 10 else 0
```

However here I have calculated foo twice. Is there a way to still write this as a one liner but avoid the double evaluation. I tried

```
foo = lambda(x): v if (v = bar(x)) > 10 else 0
```

but that doesn't work.

Comment: You can store foo(x) in a variable _tmp_ and use it in your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Preevaluate:

```
foo    = lambda(x): x if x > 10 else 0
result = foo(bar(x))
```

Here you can see what is the similarities to your code:

```
lambda (x): foo(x) if foo(x) > 10 else 0 == (lambda(x): x if x > 10 else 0)(foo(x))
```

What you seek is not possible unless you create some kind of mutable state object or some other weird trick.

@Alakazam answer is tricky and smart, use it on your own risk. It can be better using iterators and `next` to avoid extra intermediate list:

```
lambda x: next(res if res > 10 else 0 for res in (bar(x), ))
```

Here you have the [live example](https://repl.it/repls/SturdyOvalAdministration)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you *can* avoid double evaluation in a lambda. But it's really ugly, and you should avoid it. Here's how it looks:

```
foo = lambda x: next(b if b > 10 else 0 for b in [bar(x)])
```

Is this easy to read and understand? No, absolutely not. I'm not going to explain it; see if you can figure it out. This clearly isn't a good solution, so what should you do instead? You should use a real function instead of a lambda.

```
def foo(x):
    b = bar(x)
    return b if b > 10 else 0
```

This is much easier to read and clearly better.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to do this only if your function is very long to execute, else you shouldn't mind running it twice. You can't use *list comprehension*.

`foo = lambda x: [res if res>10 else 0 for res in [bar(x)]][0]`

Comment: this better I think: `lambda x: next(res if res > 10 else 0 for res in (bar(x), ))`, The reason is that you are avoiding intermediate memory allocation

Comment: @Netwave I don't think that the intermediate malloc is relevant, even if it depends on the function, you're not economizing a lot of memory.

Answer (score 0):

Might as well just define another function:

```
def bar(x):
    # some expensive calculation
    <snip>

def bar_threshold(x,t):
    y = bar(x)
    return y if y>t else 0

foo = lambda x: bar_threshold(x,10)
```

(or redefine bar, if you find yourself using it only with the threshold)

Answer (score 0):

I've tried by make some function decorator / wrapper...

```
def funcdec(func):
    def inner(x):
        if func(x) > 10:
           return func(x)
        else:
           return 0
```

then

```
@funcdec
def bar(x):
    return x * 2
```

then i try....:

```
foo = lambda x: bar(x)
```

give me result :

```
foo(2)
```

return 0
and

```
foo(10)
```

return 20